# How to remove Javascript Tag from Posted Content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Users at My website Post Content in WYSIWYG, so they can also add harmful java script and Style sheet. so just to detect java script tag in my content I've written this regex->

```
$regex = "/\<script(.*?)?\>(.|\\n)*?\<\/script\>/i";

preg_match_all($regex, $html, $scripts);

print_r($scripts);
```

regex such that print_r($scripts) will give me:

```
array(
 [0] => <script src="http://example.com"></script>
 [1] => <script>// inline js$(document).ready( function() {});</script>
 )
```

How can i do the same with stylesheet tag and remove javascript tag and stylesheet tag. above code only detect javascript how can i remove this tag

Comment: If you replace 'script' with 'style' in your regex, you should get the style tags.

Comment: ok thanks, but how can i remove these tags?

Comment: Instead of match, use replace.

Comment: `preg_replace("/<script(.*?)?\>(.|\\n)*?\<\/script\>/", "", $input_lines);`

and

`preg_replace("/<style(.*?)?\>(.|\\n)*?\<\/style\>/", "", $input_lines);`

Comment: @rock321987 for link rel="stylesheet"

Comment: Also make your replacement `greedy` as `/<script(.*?)?\>(.|\\n)*\<\/script\>/` otherwise there will be problem in nested tags

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are asking/saying?

Comment: if someone inserted like <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" />

Comment: Is this good? `<.*stylesheet.*>(.|\\n)*<\/stylesheet>`

Comment: thanks now you can post this as answer so i can i can upvote you mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing tags, you can use `preg_replace` as

```
preg_replace("/<.*script.*>(.|\\n)*<\/script>/", "", $input_lines);

preg_replace("/<.*stylesheet.*>(.|\\n)*<\/stylesheet>/", "", $input_lines);
```

There is no need to escape `<` and `>` and you can use `.*` instead of `(.*?)?`. Also I am making it `greedy` for probable nested tags by using `(.|\\n)*` instead of `(.|\\n)*?`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

$storeHere = strip_tags(whatever_you_want_to_strip_tags_from);

Comment: if i strip the tags then all <p><br><img> tag will be also removed